# How to find all subnets in network?

Tags: networking, ip

Some time ago I configured couple of routers to work like switches. I just disabled DHCP, changed IP address to something that can't (as I suppose) interfere with our current or future subnets. And forgot what it can (the subnet) be completely. Some day I want to login to it, but is there's some method to find it?

I'm trying to set my computer's ip to `192.168.0.10/16` and `10.0.0.10/8` then I realized that my computer's IP address
should be in the same subnet with this router *(For now it knows that its `/8` or `/16` subnet are "local"; accessible just from its network interface but the router don't, am I right?)*

I'm thinking about script that in the loop trying different subnets, one by one, and use something like NMAP. Or maybe there's a better solution?

---

**Update**: Routers/other devices in question have some IP's (static) like `10.241.152.34/24` (just random, for example).

Comment: You are talking about residential grade equipment here... Factory default it out and start over and document and label stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In a typical home/small business environment, the main (internet) router is the source if truth. Log into the router and find the Interfaces it knows of - along with the subnet masks and IP ranges of the router

if you have routers configured as switches you may not be able discern their IP/setuo if their IP address is opaque to the network. That said, depending on your time and setup you could portscan all the RFC1918 ranges to see what responds and use a scanner which can also look up MAC addresses to give hints about the devi e manufacturer.  (You might want to start your scans for subnets known to your router - as if a competent job was done in the first place they are likely in a range known to the router)

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you find subnets

```
for /l %a in (1,1,254) do @ping -n 1 -l 1 -w 2 192.168.%a.1 | findstr /c:"100% loss" >nul || (if errorlevel 1 echo Host 192.168.%a.1 is Up.)
```

The other way is to download a program like [Advanced IP Scanner](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/) and run a network scan like this

```
192.168.0.1-192.168.254.254
```

Edit the primary IP address of the network address and run it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).